# How to access two elements at once in a for loop without duplicates in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I have a table that looks like this:

| Celebrity | Username |
| --- | --- |
| A | user1 |
| B | user1 |
| C | user2 |
| A | user3 |
| A | user2 |
| D | user2 |
| D | user3 |

I wrote a function to find the overlaps of users between two celebrities:

```
def num_of_fans_overlap(cel1,cel2,data,Celebrity,Usernames):
    l = [cel1,cel2]
    Res = len(data.loc[data['Usernames'].map(data.groupby('Usernames').agg(set)['Celebrity'].eq(set(l)))])/2
    return print(int(Res))
```

for example, if I run num_of_fans_overlap(A,B,data,"Celebrity","Username"), I will get 1, which means one user has followed both celebrities.

Now I want to run a for loop, and the output should look like this:

```
("A", "B", 1)
("A", "C", 1)
("A", "D", 2)
("B", "C", 0)
("B", "D", 0)
("C", "D", 1)

I have been stuck here. Hope someone can help.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the function `num_of_fans_overlap` shouldn't return a `print()`.

```py
def num_of_fans_overlap(cel1,cel2,data):
    l = [cel1,cel2]
    Res = len(data.loc[data['Usernames'].map(data.groupby('Usernames').agg(set)['Celebrity'].eq(set(l)))])/2
    return int(Res)
```

Second, if the variable `celebrities` is a list of unique values on the `Celebrity` column.

```
from itertools import combinations
celebrities = list(data.Celebrity.unique())
for (cel1, cel2) in combinations(celebrities, 2):
   fans_overlap = num_of_fans_overlap(cel1, cel2, data)
   print((cel1, cel2, fans_overlap))
```

Answer (score 2):

Check with `crosstab` then `dot`

```
s = pd.crosstab(df.Celebrity,df.Username)
s = s.dot(s.T)
out = s.mask(np.triu(np.ones(s.shape)).astype(bool)).stack()
Out[301]: 
Celebrity  Celebrity
B          A            1.0
C          A            1.0
           B            0.0
D          A            2.0
           B            0.0
           C            1.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Wow, even though it is not what I am looking for, it looks very useful. I might apply this to my future work. Thank you so much for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

The naive way to do this:

```py
celebs = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
for i in range(len(celebs)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(celebs)):
        celeb_pairs = (celebs[i], celebs[j])
        run_your_function_here(*celeb_pairs, other, parameters)
```

You can also do this elegantly by using the `itertools.combinations` function:

```py
import itertools

celebs = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
for celeb1, celeb2 in itertools.combinations(celebs, 2):
    run_your_function_here
```